# Hadoop mapreduce container exited with a non-zero exit code 1

Tags: hadoop, lucene, mapreduce

I'm trying to run some hadoop program to extracting keywords of some abstracts in Ubuntu. When I run my  program using Hadoop, I get the following error.

```
 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable



INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
 WARN mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1404812840999_0001
 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1404812840999_0001
 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://shiva-VirtualBox:8088/proxy/application_1404812840999_0001/
 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1404812840999_0001
 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1404812840999_0001 running in uber mode : false
 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1404812840999_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1404812840999_0001 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1404812840999_0001_000002 exited with  exitCode: 1 due to: Exception from container-launch: org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException: 
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:505)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:418)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:650)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:195)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:283)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:79)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1
.Failing this attempt.. Failing the application.
14/07/08 14:21:44 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
```

What's the cause of this error?

Note that I converted my mapreduce project to maven project for using lucene library in my code.

Comment: can you check this property value **yarn.application.classpath** in yarn-site.xml ??

Comment: To get the real cause you may check the full application logs with the `yarn log` utility. The error you got is most probably because of a NoClassDefFoundError in the background

Answer (score 0):

Is your resource manager really on the /0.0.0.0:8032? It also seams you are not using Toolrunner, so try to rewrite your mapreduce [Hadoop: Implementing the Tool interface for MapReduce driver](http://hadoopi.wordpress.com/2013/06/05/hadoop-implementing-the-tool-interface-for-mapreduce-driver/).

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Number of thread increased, JVM memory and CPU is fully utilised. Please increase the JVM size and increase memory limit of Mapper and reducer task.
        conf.set("mapreduce.map.memory.mb", "4096");
        conf.set("mapreduce.map.java.opts", "-Xmx3500m");