# Hadoop not running tasks

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a cluster of 1 Master and 1 Slave that are connected and "probably" communicating, I have followed several guides to install and setup the cluster in which almost all of them are similar, only differences are the memory and cores assigned.

Both my master and slave have 8vcores and 32GB each, with around 600GB of SDD

[image]

However when I try to run a hadoop task I get the following message:

```
    hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-*.jar wordcount /input /output
20/11/03 15:51:34 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
20/11/03 15:51:35 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at master/master:8032
20/11/03 15:51:36 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
20/11/03 15:51:36 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
20/11/03 15:51:36 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1604418534431_0001
20/11/03 15:51:36 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1604418534431_0001
20/11/03 15:51:36 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://master:8088/proxy/application_1604418534431_0001/
20/11/03 15:51:36 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1604418534431_0001
20/11/03 15:51:43 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1604418534431_0001 running in uber mode : false
20/11/03 15:51:43 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
20/11/03 15:51:46 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1604418534431_0001_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1604418534431_0001_01_000002
Exit code: 1
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1:
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:582)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:479)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:773)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1

20/11/03 15:51:49 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1604418534431_0001_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1604418534431_0001_01_000003
Exit code: 1
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1:
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:582)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:479)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:773)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1

20/11/03 15:51:52 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1604418534431_0001_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1604418534431_0001_01_000004
Exit code: 1
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1:
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:582)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:479)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:773)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1

20/11/03 15:51:57 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
20/11/03 15:51:58 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1604418534431_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1604418534431_0001_m_000000
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0

20/11/03 15:51:58 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 16
        Job Counters
                Failed map tasks=4
                Killed reduce tasks=1
                Launched map tasks=4
                Other local map tasks=3
                Rack-local map tasks=1
                Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=3946
                Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
                Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=3946
                Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=0
                Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=3946
                Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=0
                Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=4845688
                Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=0
        Map-Reduce Framework
                CPU time spent (ms)=0
                Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
                Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=0
```

What I am trying to do is the following:

```
echo "hello world hello Hello" > ~/Downloads/test.txt

hadoop fs -mkdir /input

hadoop fs -put ~/Downloads/test.txt /input

hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-*.jar wordcount /input /output
```

Comment: Is the `/input` directory a valid directory inside the HDFS or is it locally stored? Because I think this error is shown whenever the given input fails to be found.

Comment: It is a HDFS directory, that is able to be accessed and has the file inside of it.    I can view it's content with hdfs fs /input

Comment: Searching based on the error code I found an (unchecked) SO question with one answer implying there are hardware limitations https://stackoverflow.com/a/35824511/5644037 

Plus a thread from HP regarding the same problem that indicates the YARN classpath as a problem https://community.datafabric.hpe.com/s/question/0D50L00006BIuRsSAL/mapreduce-job-failed-exited-with-exitcode-1 Are those any helpful?

Comment: @Coursal Nope, It's not a hardware limitation, neither classpath problem

Comment: You need to find the real error at `The url to track the job`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by changing the hostnames on the hosts file, I had to add an extra one that helped with the resolution of the hostname to the IP of it (apart from master)

Example:

```
<master.ip> master <hostname>
```

Thanks everyone for their help!